# How to use keydown function correctly?

Tags: jquery, keydown

Im using `keydown` for check if the input text value isn´t bigger than a value for example 10.

Im doing this:

HTML

```
<input id="number" type="text">
```

JQUERY

```
    $("#number").keydown (function(){
    var numberentered = $(this).val();
      if(numberentered < 10){
        console.log("IT IS NOT BIGGER THAN 10");
      }else{
        console.log("IT IS BIGGER THAN 10");
      }
    });
```

If the number is `< 10` all work, but when the number is for example in this case 11 it not work.

```js
$("#number").keydown (function(){
    var numberentered = $(this).val();
      if(numberentered < 10){
        console.log("IT IS NOT BIGGER THAN 10");
      }else{
        console.log("IT IS BIGGER THAN 10");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" type="text">
```

If I change `keydown` for `keyup` it work but I want use `keydown` and know why it isn´t working.

All help is welcome, greetings and thanks in advance!!

Comment: @Taplar It makes sense what you say, thanks for your contribution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question of **why** it does not work, is because `keydown` fires before the value changes, not after.  You want to use `input` or `keyup` or one of the other events that happens after the value changes instead.

```js
$("#number").keydown (function(){
    var numberentered = $(this).val();
console.log(numberentered);
      if(numberentered < 10){
        console.log("IT IS NOT BIGGER THAN 10");
      }else{
        console.log("IT IS BIGGER THAN 10");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" type="text">
```

Comment: this code is incorrect, if you type 3 characters you will get "IT IS BIGGER THAN 10" because you need to use $(this).val().length to capture the correct value;

Comment: @MarioPerez Of course this code is incorrect.  The answer is the same as the question, demonstrating with a console.log **why** their logic did not work, which was the question.  However, even a length check on the value will not be a complete fix.  Would you say that "000" is greater than ten?  What about "009"? Or what about exactly "10"?  There is more to the logic the user is developing than just a length check.  However, with regard to an answer as to why their logic did not work as they expected, this **is** an answer.